# Appending list of lists to data frame in single column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, rvest

I am Working on below code in r to scrape a web page info :

```
library(rvest)
crickbuzz <- read_html(httr::GET("http://www.cricbuzz.com/cricket -match/live-scores"))
matches_dates <- crickbuzz %>%
html_nodes(".schedule-date:nth-child(1)")%>%
html_attr("timestamp")

matches_dates
[1] "1452268800000" "1452132000000" "1452247200000" "1452242400000" "1452327000000" "1452290400000" "1452310200000" "1452310200000" "1452310200000"
[10] "1452310200000" "1452324600000" "1452324600000" "1452324600000" "1452324600000" "1452324600000" "1452150000000" "1452153600000" "1452153600000"
```

now i am converting it to proper date and time format

```
dates <- lapply(X = matches_date ,  function(timestamp_match){
 (as.POSIXct(as.numeric(timestamp_match)/1000, origin="1970-01-01")) })
```

and now i have dates in the below form :

```
     dates
[[1]]
[1] "2016-01-10 07:30:00 IST"

[[2]]
[1] "2016-01-10 21:30:00 IST"

[[3]]
[1] "2016-01-09 12:00:00 IST"

[[4]]
[1] "2016-01-10 13:55:00 IST"

[[5]]
[1] "2016-01-10 10:50:00 IST"

[[6]]
[1] "2016-01-07 12:30:00 IST"

[[7]]
[1] "2016-01-07 13:30:00 IST"

[[8]]
[1] "2016-01-10 09:00:00 IST"

[[9]]
[1] "2016-01-10 09:00:00 IST"

[[10]]
[1] "2016-01-10 09:00:00 IST"

[[11]]
[1] "2016-01-10 09:00:00 IST"

[[12]]
[1] "2016-01-10 09:00:00 IST"

[[13]]
[1] "2016-01-10 13:00:00 IST"

[[14]]
[1] "2016-01-10 13:00:00 IST"

[[15]]
[1] "2016-01-10 13:00:00 IST"

[[16]]
[1] "2016-01-10 13:00:00 IST"

[[17]]
[1] "2016-01-10 03:30:00 IST"

[[18]]
[1] "2016-01-10 03:30:00 IST"
```

now i am appending this to one column of data frame :

matches_info[,"Date And Time"] <- dates

but only 1st date is getting copied over whole column and giving below warning.

```
Warning message:
 In `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, , "Date And Time", value = list(1452391200,  :
 provided 18 variables to replace 1 variables
```

and if i will do unlist(dates) it is giving me timestamps again. How can i extrate date and time ??

Comment: Eventually you can do `dates <- sapply(X = matches_date , ...)` instead of `lapply`

Comment: Which is the need of `lapply`? Doesn't `as.POSIXct(as.numeric(matches_date)/1000, origin="1970-01-01")` suffice? All the functions involved are vectorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `do.call(c, dates)` instead of `unlist(dates)` to prevent R from converting the list elements to numeric and keeping them POSIXct:

```
matches_date <- c("1452268800000", "1452132000000")
dates <- lapply(X = matches_date ,  function(timestamp_match){
 (as.POSIXct(as.numeric(timestamp_match)/1000, origin="1970-01-01")) })
do.call(c, dates)
# [1] "2016-01-08 17:00:00 CET" "2016-01-07 03:00:00 CET"

matches_info[,"Date And Time"] <- do.call(c, dates)
```

or simply

```
matches_date <- c("1452268800000", "1452132000000")
matches_info[,"Date And Time"] <- as.POSIXct(as.numeric(matches_date)/1000, origin="1970-01-01")
```

Comment: The lapply isn't necessary as all the functions inside it are already vectorised